# Redirect traffic from one frontend to another based on ip address

Tags: haproxy, access-control-list

I would like to redirect the traffic on haproxy from one frontend to another based on ip/subnet . I'm aware of how to do this via ACL's after recieving it on one frontend. However, I don't want the traffic to be decrypted/ ssl terminated before it is forwarded to another frontend. Basically, the SSL termination should take place at the last frontend I want the traffic to be received on. How can I achieve this ?